# Driver is not loading when there 2 or more source files

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have defined the following files

main.c file

```
#include "main.h"

static int __int entrypoint(void)
{
        pr_info("Helloworld");
        new_function(void);
        return 0;
}

static void __exit exitpoint(void)
{
        pr_info("Goodbye World");
}

module_init(entrypoint);
module_exit(exitpoint);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SSV");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("SIMPLE DRIVER");
MODULE_INFO(X86, "X86-64bit");
```

function.c file

```
#include "main.h"
void new_function(void)
{
        pr_info("hello new function \n");
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

main.h file

```
#include <linux/module.h>

void new_function(void);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m := main.o
main-objs :=function.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

When i used make it successfully generated main.ko but when i tried to load the module i am getting the following error

[ 2991.240255] main: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 2991.240263] main: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

I was expecting module to be loaded and print statements to be printed from both the files

Comment: You don't compile the source `main.c` into your module. With line `main-objs :=function.o` you only compile `function.c` into it. You cannot compile the module from several times and **name the module as one of those files**. You need either to rename your module (e.g. into `hello`) or rename your `main.c` file (e.g. into `main_module.c`).